# 1G communications between two SFP/SFP+ ports

Tags: sfp

I have two Arista switches and I would like them to communicate in 1G through a direct link.

I know of three of options:

1. Use copper RJ45 and SFP-to-RJ45 transceivers on both ends
2. Use optical, with SFP to 1000BASE-SX transceivers
3. Use optical, with SFP to 1000BASE-LX transceivers

Are there other options where there's some sort of 1G "direct attach" no requiring external transceivers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't mentioned what model switches you have, but there are more than a few types of SFP  connectors, the 1000BASE-T (SFP to Gb Ethernet) and SX models are for short distance connectivity (although the fiber will go much longer distances than the copper), LX, EX, ZX, EZX, [and so on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_form-factor_pluggable_transceiver#Types) which are for 10km+ distances.

I am making the assumption that these switches have no RJ-45 ports, as that would make plain copper cabling another possible connection method.

The only other type of "direct attach" connectivity I can think of would be the stacking cables, but that's very probably debatable.

Comment: The switches are 7124 and 7148, which only have SFP/SFP+ connectors. What do you mean by "stacking cables"?

Comment: Well, if the switches are compatible, you can use stacking cables to create a much larger single managed switch instead.

Comment: Just had a look at the models, doesn't look like they are actually stackable.

Answer (score 0):

The Arista switch that you have mentioned can support the following interface. [Arista switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15sYM.jpg)

Choose which type of cabling or optical transceiver depends on your cost and distance. Hope this helps !